# Media path not read in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem on how can I retrieve my images through using media file in Django. Currently I just want to display images based on their path in Database. Based on the console image below the `{{MEDIA-URL}}` does not recognize/read, it only  read this tag `{{img_photos.photos}}`. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

I followed this documentation [link](https://roytuts.com/working-with-media-files-in-django-templates/) but it seems it's not working.

[image]

*view_gallery.html*

```
  {% for img_photos in photos %}
    <div class="card-body px-0">
      <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{img_photos.photos}}"/> #it seems {{media-url}} didn't read/recognize
      <h4 class="card-title">{{img_photos.photos}}</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below.</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

*App - urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
path('view_gallery/<int:pk>/',views.view_gallery, name='view_gallery'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

*views.py*

```
def view_gallery(request,pk):
   path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT #I didn't use this don't know yet how to implement 
   image = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = pk)
   data = {'photos':image} #the output is like this PHotos/image.jpg
   return render(request, 'view_gallery.html', data)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url for a file uploaded to a `FileField` or `ImageField` can be accessed via it's [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) attribute

```
<img src="{{ img_photos.photos.url }}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used it and It does read the media path but it didn't  display the image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8rNz.png) Is there any restriction to edit in settings.py?

Comment: What is your `MEDIA_URL` setting? You might need to prefix it with a slash: `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Comment: .This is my media looks like in my settings.py `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'` and my media root `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

Comment: Add a slash to the beginning of `MEDIA_URL`: `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`